# Почему DOMParser не парсит DOM-структуру?

Tags: javascript, html, парсер, dom

Почему у меня DOMParser не парсит следующую довольно простую DOM-структуру?

```
var newDOM ="<div><strong>Error!</strong> Refresh, Please... </div>",
    parser = new DOMParser(),
    doc = parser.parseFromString(xmlString, "text/xml");
```

> ReferenceError: xmlString is not defined

Comment: 1) У вас переменная называется `newDOM`, а не `xmlString`. Вы текст ошибки то читали?
2) Не `text/xml`, а `text/html`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В ошибке написано:

> Ошибка при ссылке: переменная `xmlString` не найдена.

Вам нужно при вызове функции `parser.parseFromString` передавать в неё переменную `newDOM` вот так:

```
var newDOM ="<div><strong>Error!</strong> Refresh, Please... </div>",
    parser = new DOMParser(),
    doc = parser.parseFromString(newDOM, "text/html");
```

И ещё: не касается этой ошибки, но касается ошибки в будущем:
Поскольку ваша строка `newDOM` является HTML-строкой, то и писать нужно `"text/html"`, а не `"text/xml"` во втором параметре функции `parser.parseFromString`.

Answer (score 1):

В ошибке все написано. ДОМ-структура лежит в `newDOM`, а парсить вы пытаетесь `xmlString`.